# Comparing Two Data-Frames and Creating A New Data-Frame with Unique Elements

Tags: r

I have two data frames. I want to compare them and create a new data frame with full names of df1 that are not found in df2. I am trying to find names in df1 whose first name is not present in df2.

df1:

```
   names
 1 Sally Williams
 2 Tom Hacker
 3 Jane Turner
 4 John Murray
 5 Marry Kelly Parker
 6 David Carlson Smith
```

df2:

```
  first_names
1 Kendall
2 Tom 
3 Jane 
4 Sarah
5 David
```

I want to create a new data-frame with names not found in df2

df_new

```
  unique_names
1 Sally Williams
2 John Murray
3 Marry Kelly Parker
```

Comment: So you don't want anyone with a first name from the df2 list?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: @kumkiee I showed 3 methods and all of them worked on your two examples

Answer (score 3):

You could `split` the string on whitespace, get the first name and then find the names which are not present in `first_names` of `df2`.

```
df1[!sapply(strsplit(df1$names, "\\s+"),`[`, 1) %in% df2$first_names,, drop = FALSE]

#           names
#1 Sally Williams
#4    John Murray
```

---

Or a `tidyverse` approach would be

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  separate(names, into = c("first_names", "last_names")) %>%
  anti_join(df2) %>%
  unite(unique_names, sep = " ")
```

Comment: I am getting this error when I run the above code Error in strsplit(df1$names, "\\s+") : 
  non-character argument

Comment: @kumkiee `names` is factor it seems. Run `df1$names <- as.character(df1$names)` first and then run the above code.

Comment: I tried tidyverse approach and I got the following error message: Error: `by` required, because the data sources have no common variables
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
In addition: Warning message:
Expected 2 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 531 rows [9, 11, 41, 56, 67, 74, 76, 77, 78, 109, 121, 135, 138, 139, 151, 152, 154, 164, 165, 175, ...].

Comment: Some people have middle names.

Comment: @kumkiee In that case, first approach should work. Try that one.

Comment: The first approach returns exactly every name on df1

Comment: @kumkiee sorry, it should have been other way round. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @ Ronak Shah Unfortunately, your updated code still returns only the names of df1.

Comment: @kumkiee I am not clear what you mean by names of `df1`. You have only names in `df1` right? This should return you names in `df1` whose first name is not present in `df2`. What else do you expect it to return? Can you also convert f`irst_names` to character as well? Run `df2$first_names <- as.character(df2$first_names)` Not sure if that is giving unexpected result.

Comment: @ Ronak Shah Yes, I am trying to find names in df1 whose first name is not present in df2. Your code just returns names of df1 (Sally Williams, Tom Hacker, Jane Turner, John Murray, Marry Kelly Parker, David Carlson Smith)

Comment: @kumkiee and what do you expect it to return? Did you use `drop = FALSE` as shown in the answer?

Comment: I am expecting it to return names in df1 whose first name is not present in df2 (Sally Williams, John Murray, Marry Kelly Parker). However, your code is returning every name listed in df1 (Sally Williams, Tom Hacker, Jane Turner, John Murray, Marry Kelly Parker, David Carlson Smith). Yes, I used the  drop = FALSE as shown in the answer.

Comment: @kumkiee that is strange though. Does it work on the sample data you provided? It works for me, can you verify it on your end?

Comment: Yes, it does work in the sample data. The real data frame df2 has other columns other than first_names. Maybe they are somehow causing an issue ?

Comment: No that should not be an issue. Can you update your post with `head(dput(df1))` and `head(dput(df2))` ?

Comment: Actually, this code does not work on the sample data either. It just gives df1. I am reading data from cvs files, maybe this causes an issue?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `regex_anti_join`

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
regex_anti_join(df1, df2, by = c("names" = "first_names")) %>% 
       tibble(unique_names = .)
# A tibble: 2 x 1
#  unique_names  
#   <chr>         
#1 Sally Williams
#2 John Murray
```

It also works with the second updated dataset

```
regex_anti_join(df1N, df2N, by = c("names" = "first_names")) %>% 
       tibble(unique_names = .)
# A tibble: 3 x 1
#  unique_names      
#   <chr>             
#1 Sally Williams    
#2 John Murray       
#3 Marry Kelly Parker
```

---

Or another option is to create the 'first_name' with `word`, do a `anti_join` and then get the output

```
library(dplyr)
df1N  %>% 
   mutate(first_names = word(names, 1)) %>%
   anti_join(df2N) %>% 
   select(names(df1N))
#               names
#1     Sally Williams
#2        John Murray
#3 Marry Kelly Parker
```

Or another option is `word` from `stringr` to extract the first name and then use `%in%` to find the elements that match in the second dataset, negate (`!`) and subset the rows of the first dataset

```
library(stringr)
df1N[!word(df1N$names, 1) %in% df2N$first_names,, drop = FALSE]
#               names
#1     Sally Williams
#4        John Murray
#5 Marry Kelly Parker
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(names = c("Sally Williams", "Tom Hacker", "Jane Turner", 
"John Murray")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4"))

df2 <- structure(list(first_names = c("Kendall", "Tom", "Jane", "Sarah"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))
```

---

```
df1N <- structure(list(names = c("Sally Williams", "Tom Hacker", 
 "Jane Turner", 
"John Murray", "Marry Kelly Parker", "David Carlson Smith")), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))

df2N <- structure(list(first_names = c("Kendall", "Tom", "Jane", "Sarah", 
"David")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5"))
```

Comment: Some people have middle names, some people even have 2 middle names (James R. R. Williams). Would this code still work ?

Comment: I see. Well the actual data frames have hundreds of names, so I couldn't copy all of them here.

Comment: @kumkiee  I understand, but I find the pattern here you showed

Comment: @kumkiee Based on two examples you posted, it is working fine for me

Answer (score -1):

```
library(dplyr)
```

you can use the following:

```
setdiff(data_frame_name1, data_frame_name2)
```

or

```
semi_join(data_frame_name1, data_frame_name2)
```

or

```
anti_join(data_frame_name1, data_frame_name2)
```